# Facebook Like Button to link to Homepage or Fanpage?

Tags: facebook, button, facebook-like

I am going to install a facebook like button on my Homepage (of a large forum). I already have like buttons at the bottom of each post but currently no like button for the Homepage of the forum.

I wondered is there a way that when they like the Homepage, the also become a fan of the fan page with the same click or do I need 2 seperate like buttons.

I ask because if I link the like button to the fanpage, I will gain more fans but the Homepage of the site will not be gaining social presence?

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to make a Like button "like" two different things with one click.

You need a separate Like button for the Fan page.